# How to pass text to Google Voice SMS Programmatically?

Tags: android, sms, voice

```
I use the following code to start the SMS application:   

Intent smsIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,   Uri.parse("sms:"));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Message Body");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

It works fine if user selects standard "Messaging" application. But if user selects GV the message body text is ignored.

I have also tried the following as suggested in some forums:

smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message Body");

I have searched all the forums I know of and tried lot of things. Nothing worked for me.  Am I missing something here? Does GV need a special handing that it can’t be treated as regular “Messaging” app?

Comment: Try `smsto:` instead of `sms:` and see if that helps.

Comment: Changing "sms" to "smsto" didn't help.

Comment: Jas: did you ever get an answer to this problem?  I'm running into the same issue and can't figure out any way to get the text to show up in the message body in GV.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts that might point you in the right direction:

- [Google Voice SMS intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386326/google-voice-sms-intent)
- [Sending SMS using Intent does not add recipients on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242190/sending-sms-using-intent-does-not-add-recipients-on-some-devices)
- [what is the difference between ACTION_SENDTO and ACTION_VIEW when sending sms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341078/what-is-the-difference-between-action-sendto-and-action-view-when-sending-sms)
- Here's a third party library for accessing Google Voice: http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/ ...except it directly accesses Google Voice via its web URLs...
- [Here's](http://android-x86.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=android-x86/korg_packages_apps_Mms.git;a=commitdiff_plain;h=d669a2b2fcde0f588944af6caaca814a1bd4e92d) some old (2010) Android MMS source where they manually accessed Google Voice, which might give some bonus hints:
- Also try putting it in an extra called `"data"` or `"pdudata"`
- Also, [here's](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/mms/data/WorkingMessage.java.html) some more (old?) source mentioning some intent extras including `"android.mms.extra.MESSAGE"`

Hopefully one of these help you out...