# SMS body is not changing its text in intent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am working on app, i am using `intent` to launch sms activity. I set the `sms_body` of the `intent`, after a while i changed the text of `sms_body` and `recepients` too but now when i launch the sms activity it show old text and old recepients.

I even clean the project. I debug as well, the values are setting correctly, but on activity launch it shows old text and recepients.

EDIT:

when i do the following code:

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                    String primaryandsecondaryNumbers=PrimaryNumber+";"+SecondaryNumber;

                    String messageBody="MY MESSAGE";
                   intent.putExtra("address", primaryandsecondaryNumbers);
                  intent.putExtra("sms_body", messageBody);
                  intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + primaryandsecondaryNumbers));
                  intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                  startActivity(intent);
```

My messageBody is not updated but recepient numbers are set.

and when i comment:

```
         intent.putExtra("address", primaryandsecondaryNumbers);
```

my message is updated, but my numbers are not visible

Comment: Post some code and give more information.

Comment: the answer of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242190/sending-sms-using-intent-does-not-add-recipients-on-some-devices SO question helped me as i've removed setType

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the draft saved for the recepient.
If you change recepient and draft is not exist for him then it set new message.
If you delete a draft that will work.

Comment: Any idea how to override this draft?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the HTC Sensation. The only way to construct the intent and get everything updated correctly is by using this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra("address", "123456");
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Message Body");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:123456")); //yes, you need the number twice
activity.startActivity(intent);
```