# What are the possible workarounds for the new Google Policy Change for SEND_SMS?

Tags: android, android-permissions

This is the link provided by the new [play store Permissions Policy](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/). We need to have SEND_SMS feature as our primary mode of authentication.  so we need to create a workaround. We tried with the Intent. But it is not giving any success callbacks. we need this call back to make sure the SMS is sent or not.

```
private void invokeSMSIntent(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    Intent sendIntent;
    if ("".equals(phoneNumber) && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this.cordova.getActivity());

        sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null) {
            sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }
    } else {
        sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
        // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242190/sending-sms-using-intent-does-not-add-recipients-on-some-devices
        sendIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
        sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(phoneNumber)));
    }
    this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(sendIntent);
    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK));
}
```

Comment: we need to verify the phone number. API auth is there but SMS sending is the foolproof method we can trust.

Comment: This is not about free sms pack. Please come back to the question. It is about how to solve this problem. I need to get the callback. If sms is send of failed. Thank you.